# Execute shell commands at the startup on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I've to execute a shell commands at the startup.

```
java -jar selenium....
```

I tried with this but nothing:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init.d/nomescript.sh 
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/nomescript.sh
sudo update-rc.d nomescript.sh defaults
```

Do you know how I can do this?

Thank you!!
Marco

Comment: If programs in your script depend on other resources being up and running, you need to specify priorities in your update-rc.d command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has abandoned SysV init script approach to booting the system.

This link explains how to create an Upstart script and how to run it at boot - http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7033/1/

Comment: I don't understand a thing: 
if I execute the shell command at the startup it works but selenium gives me an error, if I execute the same command in the terminal all works..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a line to your crontab:

```
@reboot command here
```

That pretty much guarantees it won't happen more than once (like /etc/rc.local or gnome sessions)
It also lets you ensure it is run as the correct user very easily.